# Most-specific matching wild card path

Tags: string, language-agnostic, path, pattern-matching

Given a resource structure of Unix-like paths:

e.g.

```
/foo/bar/baz/phleem/abc.txt
```

and a set of ant-style wildcard patterns:

```
*  matches zero or more characters excluding /
** matches zero or more full sub-paths (may not be preceded or followed
   by anything other than /)
```

All other characters in patterns are literals, and for simplicity's sake, only the characters

> A-Z, a-z, 0-9, / and .

are allowed in paths.

Given the above structure:

**Am I correct in assuming that of all matching patterns, the most specific match is always the alphabetically last?**

Example:

Path:

```
/foo/bar/baz/phleem/abc.txt
```

Matching patterns (in alphabetical order):

```
**               < least specific
**/*.txt
**/phleem/*.txt
/foo/**/abc.txt  < most specific
```

Update: OK, here's my definition of "most specific"

a is more specific than b if

1. the non-wildcard prefix of a is longer than that of b
2. given two wildcards at the same respective offset, * is more specific than **

Comment: It is not clear why do you think `**/phleem/*.txt` is "less specific" then `/foo/**/abc.txt`. Of the two sets of paths they respectively match, neither one is contained in the other.

Comment: @n.m. you're right, I'm going to elaborate on that, shortly. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the specificity be a function of the number of wildcards?  I can agree that ** > * but I think you should also include that * * > *.  The condition on the non-wildcard prefix length seems rather artificial.  Why is /foo/bar/a*n*y*t*h*i*n*g more specific than foo/*/anything?

Comment: @tripleee because otherwise this problem is unsolvable, I guess :-) No, it just makes more sense in an application I am developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking you're not doing an alphabetical ordering since `/` and `*` are not letters, so it would be a lexicographical ordering. It appears you're already assuming `*` < `[a-zA-Z0-9./]` which is important. Ordering the patterns as such will satisfy your first condition that the non-wildcard prefix is of maximum length. However, the ordering will only ensure that `*` is used over `**` in the first non-equal case; all remaining wildcards become irrelevant to the ordering. This could be a problem. Consider the following two patterns:

```
/**/*.txt
/*/**
```

They are ordered, but I would argue the first is actually more specific.

Comment: It’s weird that people use “lexicographic” to mean an ordering that is completely antagonistic to anything a *real* lexicographer would ever use when ordering dictionary or phonebook entries.  Numeric code point order is nothing like a proper alphabetic / dictionary / lexicographer’s order; it’s pretty much junk, actually.

Comment: @Kevin I define alphabetic order strictly in terms of the order in the ASCII charset. You are right, your special case would break my assumption, even though it's unlikely to occur. Thanks.